# Local debugging endpoint with localhost and remote endpoint with custom domain are not consistent

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a `Firebase` + `Cloud Function API` + `Express` API with the following files:

**/functions/index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/api/echo', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: req.query.message,
  });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**/firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api",
        "region": "us-central1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To test the app on **LOCAL** I run the following command:

```
$ firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
```

To access the endpoint on **LOCAL** I go to the following url:

```
[1] http://localhost:5001/[my-project]/us-central1/api/api/echo/?message=Hello+World
```

To deploy the app to `Firebase` (**REMOTE**) I run the following command:

```
$ firebase deploy --only hosting,functions
```

To access the endpoint with Google domain I go to the following url:

```
[2] https://us-central1-[my-project].cloudfunctions.net/api/api/echo/?message=Hello+World
```

To access the endpoint with my custom domain I go to the following url:

```
[3] https://www.[mydomain.tld]/api/echo/?message=Hello+World
```

With all 3 urls above I get the following (expected) output:

```
{"message":"Hello World"}
```

**My problem is:** On urls: `[1]` and `[2]` I need to specify `/api` twice (please check above). I would like to configure things around in order to just need to specify: `/api` once on urls: `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`. It doesn't look good to me having to specify: `/api` twice.

It is a requirement for me to access the endpoints after: `/api/` because on the parent level I have a web app that uses the endpoints.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!